# Derive a closed form expression for number of observations having a probability greater than a threshold?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

P is the probability of an event and is defined as

$P=\exp({A\log(1-\beta}))$

Given that $\beta\in(0,1)$ and $A>0$, So we have $P\in(0,1)$

Now I conduct an experiment, where I perform the following steps for $N$ iterations

for $i = 1$ to $N$

1. Assign a random value for $\beta\in(0,1)$
2. Calculate $P$

end

Now the question is: Find the probability distribution function for the number of iterations $M$ ($<N$) where $P > P_c$ ($=0.5$, say).

This could be easily done numerically using a computer program, however, I am interested to derive the closed form expression for the same.

I assume that $\beta$ follows a uniform distribution. How do I find the distribution function for $M$ ?

Comment: In other words, letting $a=1-\beta$, you want to count number of occurencies of $a^A>P_c$ within $N$ tries? The answer: you cannot. $M$ is a random variable too. You maybe can calculate it's expecteg value or variance or whetever, but not the $M$ itself. Let's see.. $A\log a>\log P_c$, divide by $A$ you'll have a [binomial ditribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) for $M$.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin - Do you mean $a^A$ rather than $A^a$ ?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin, Thanks for the insight. I have two follow up questions: a) How do we know its a binomial distribution b) how do we obtain the mean and variance ?

Comment: @Henry you're right, $3$am here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the $i$th iteration you generate $\beta_i\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ and $P_i=(1-\beta_i)^A$. Define
$$X_i=\begin{cases}1,&& \text{if }P_i>P_c\\
0,&& \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases}$$
so the $X_i$ are $\text{Bernoulli}(p)$ random variables with $p=P(X_i=1)=P(P_i>P_c)=P((1-\beta_i)^A>P_c)=P(\beta_i<1-P_c^{1/A})=1-P_c^{1/A}$.

Assuming the $\beta_i$ are independent, so are the $X_i$, hence the distribution of the sum $M=X_1+...+X_N$ must be $\text{Binomial}(N,p)$, whose mean and variance are therefore $Np$ and $Np(1-p)$, respectively. (See any textbook, or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), for the PMF, CDF, etc.)

**NB**: The CDF of a Binomial distribution has no "closed form", but is a finite sum that can be represented as an incomplete beta function.

Comment: Thanks very much. I took N=10000 & A = 1.7315. I programmed it in Matlab, obtained M as 3298 ( I sampled for 10000 times and took a mean), But if I use the formula for expected value i.e. Np = 10000*0.6988 = 6988. Why is this discrepancy ? In fact, I checked if $\beta$ follows a uniform distribution and it does

Comment: @Mechanician With $N=10000, A=1.7315,$ and $P_c=0.5$, we have $p=1-0.5^{1/1.7315}=0.32989...$, giving $Np=3298.9...$, which is consistent with your simulated value of $\overline{M}={1\over 1000}(M_1+...+M_{10000})=3298.$ Note that a 95% confidence interval for the expected value of $\overline{M}$ has endpoints $\overline{M}\pm 1.96\sigma_{\overline{M}}$, where $\sigma_{\overline{M}}=\sqrt{V(\overline{M})}=\sqrt{{1\over 1000}V(M_1)}=\sqrt{{1\over 1000}\cdot Np(1-p)}=\sqrt{p(1-p)}.$ With your results this is $3298\pm 0.92..$, which does (just barely) cover the expected value $Np=3298.9...$

Comment: Thank you very much. I messed up in calculating p (I did it as $p=1-P_c^A$)